# Producing an anaglyph rendering with LWJGL?

Tags: java, lwjgl

How to produce an anaglyph rendering with LWJGL ?

Help me!
Thanks

Comment: This is an OpenGL-related question, not an LWJGL-related one. LWJGL only handles user input and window handling. The rest is OpenGL/OpenAL/OpenCL.

Answer (score 2):

You have to render two views, one for each eye, with each view slightly shifted to the left or right.  Then, you overlay the views with red and cyan/blue color masks on each (glColorMask).

Try looking through this page: http://local.wasp.uwa.edu.au/~pbourke/texture_colour/anaglyph/